# Get the maximum row of a dictionary in Python grouped by key based on value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to retrieve per year the maximum gross acumulated of all genres in the following list:

```
consolidado = sorted(
    [[row_2[0],row_2[1],row_2[2][x]]for row_2 in [[row["gross"], row["title_year"],row["genres"].split("|")] for row in list if len(row["gross"]) > 0 and len(row["title_year"])>0] for x in  range(len(row_2[2]))],
    key=(lambda x: x[1]))

ranking = {}
for row in sorted(consolidado,key=lambda x:x[1]):
    ranking.update({(row[1],row[2]):0})

for row in consolidado:
    ranking[(row[1],row[2])] += int(row[0])
```

So far with the code above i was able to get the sum of all movie gross per year per genre, but i have been trying for two days to get the code that compares all genres gross for one year and i have come with nothing i could use.

The data i'm having

```
Consolidado List

[['1920',[Drama,Comedy,Action],100]['1920',[Fantasy,Comedy,Drama],100]]
[['1927',[Drama],100]['1927',[Horror,Suspense,Drama],100]]

Ranking

{1920,Action:100}
{1920,Fantasy:100}
{1920,Comedy:200}

{1927,Drama:200}
{1927,Horror:100}
{1927,Suspense:100}
```

That for 100 years and 5k movies with several genres each movie

Comment: Could you share some of the data you're working with.  It's a little unclear from this what the dictionary actually looks like

Comment: I have edited the question with the data example

Comment: Make a dictionary that maps years to dictionaries that map genres to profits  something like `{1920: {'Horror': 100, 'Drama': 15}, 1915: {'Comedy': 115}}`.  Then you can do a dictionary comprehension so sum the values for the subdictionaries `{k: sum(v.values()) for k, v in d}`